# Oracle Apex Interactive report formatting and sorting

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive report with floats and I want to sort the values in the correct way like:

```
8.00
9.00
80.00
90.00
```

In addition I want to show only two decimal places.

By default Apex displays this format:

[image]

How the achieve the correct formatting?

Edit:
The Data type of the column was not numeric but Varchar. After chasnging the type to number all formatting were as expected.

Comment: What is the datatype of your column?

Comment: Ok I see, format was Varchar. After converting to number it worked. Thanks Scott for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your IR has the following columns:

- ID
- Amount

#### Order by

Set the order by statement:

1. Click on the IR
2. Find the **Source** attribute on the right
3. Click on **Order By** and set the value to (choose one):

- AMOUNT DESC
- AMOUNT ASC

#### Format

The format should be set on column level on the left screen find the AMOUNT column under the IR. Now on the right you should find an attribute called **Format Mask** (under Appearance).

Set the value to: `FM9999999.90` (choose one predefined)

#### SQL

Or just use an SQL query:

```
select ID,
       TO_CHAR(AMOUNT, 'FM9999999.90') AMOUNT,
  from TEST_TABLE
order by AMOUNT DESC
```

Comment: None of the suggestions is working for me. Could there be another problem?

Comment: Hmm.... Can you re-create the problem on APEX live.... Which APEX version do you have?

Comment: Thanks, the data type of the column was not correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a format mask on the column definition.
[image: format mask setting on column]

The LOV next to the setting gives some samples

```
999G999G999G999G990D00
```

Sorting will be as expected if this table's column is numeric.

Answer (score 2):

In Interactive report: Actions > Data > Sort, select column and set Ascending Direction;
In Page Designer: Choose your column and set Format Mask in Appearance section, for example: 99.99.